# send email reminders on particular dates and have no idea about cron job

Tags: php, zend-framework

Suffering with an issue related to sending email reminders on some particular date. I have searched for some helpful codes and several sites says about cron job. But I have no more idea about the same. So anyone let tel me the actual answer. Here I attach the code.

```
include('connection.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name       = $_POST['name'];
$mobile     = $_POST['mobile'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$datenoted  = $_POST['datenoted'];
$subject    = $_POST['subject'];
$sel = "insert into reminders(remindr_name,remindr_mobile,reminder_email,remindr_subject,remindr_date,curdate,curtime) values('$name','$mobile','$email','$subject','$datenoted',CURDATE(),CURTIME())";
if(!mysqli_query($link ,$sel ))
{
echo "Error " .mysqli_error($link);
}
else
 {

$sqlCommand = "SELECT 
        u.remindr_id
        , remindr_name
        , remindr_subject
        , remindr_date
        , reminder_email
        FROM reminders u
        WHERE remindr_date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE()+INTERVAL 7 DAY
        ";

        $query = mysqli_query($link, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error($link));

        //fetch the data from the database 
$message = '';
$email = '';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $arr_ids[] = $row['remindr_id'];

       $prev_Email = $email;
        $headers = "From: mail@georgeprojects.com\r\n";    
        $subject = "GeorgeProject Reminder";
        $id = $row['id'];
        $owner = $row['remindr_name'];
        $email = $row['reminder_email'];

if(date("Y-m-d") == $row['remindr_date']) {

if(!empty($email) && $email != ""){
$message = "Hi: {$row['remindr_name']} , \n\n There is a reminder for you on the date : {$row['remindr_date']} regarding the subject {$row['remindr_subject']}\n";

    $to = $email;
    $sendmail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

 }
 }

 }

header('Location: reminderInsert.php');
} 
}
```

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you haven't tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your existing code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: You can read up on cronjob/crontab on the web. You basically run a script every X minutes, which gets the relevant data from your database and sends email accordingly. If there is no data, this script does nothing.